# Android: "Cannot convert from object to Album" (Album is a class..)

Tags: android, lazy-loading, adapter

New to android here, (and programming in general)

I'm following this example trying to create a lazy image loading adapter: http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2012/06/13/lazy-loading-images-from-urls-to-listviews/ 
I'm using "Album" instead of Student, but the rest is pretty much the same.

When I call the following from my adapter:

```
Album getItem(int position) {
    return items.get(position);
}
```

I get "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to Album". I tried copying the code from the example verbatim, and I got the same error..

Could somebody please explain what I am doing wrong, and how to fix it? Thank you.

Here is the code:

Album class:

```
package another.music.player;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public class Album {

    private String album;

    private String imageUri;

    private Bitmap image;

    private AlbumAdapter albumAdapter;

    public Album(String album, String imageUri) {

        this.album = album;
        this.imageUri = imageUri;

        // Default image
        this.album = null;
    }

    public String getAlbum() {
        return album;
    }

    public void setAlbum(String album) {
        this.album = album;
    }

    public String getImageUri() {
        return imageUri;
    }

    public void setImageUri(String imageUri) {
        this.imageUri = imageUri;
    }

    public Bitmap getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public AlbumAdapter getAdapter() {
        return albumAdapter;
    }

    public void setAdapter(AlbumAdapter albumAdapter) {
        this.albumAdapter = albumAdapter;
    }

    public void loadImage(AlbumAdapter albumAdapter) {
        // Hold a reference to the adapter
        this.albumAdapter = albumAdapter;
        if (imageUri != null && !imageUri.equals("")) {
            new ImageLoadTask().execute(imageUri);
        }
    }

    // Async task
    private class ImageLoadTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Bitmap> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Log.i("ImageLoadTask", "Loading Image..");
        }

        // Param[0] is Image URI
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... param) {
            Log.i("ImageLoadTask", "Attempting to load image Uri: " + param[0]);
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = ImageService.getBitmapFromURI(param[0]);
                return bitmap;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
            // No Op
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap ret) {
            if (ret != null) {
                Log.i("ImageLoadTask", "Successfully loaded" + album + " image");
                image = ret;
                if (albumAdapter != null) {
                    // When image is loaded, notify the adapter
                    albumAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ImageLoadTask", "Failed to load " + album + " image");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

AlbumAdapter Class:

```
package another.music.player;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AlbumAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    private List items = new ArrayList();

    public AlbumAdapter(Context context, List items) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.items = items;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    public Album getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        Album album = items.get(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.name.setText(album.getName());
        if (s.getImage() != null) {
            holder.pic.setImageBitmap(s.getImage());
        } else {
                // MY DEFAULT IMAGE
            holder.pic.setImageResource(R.drawable.generic_profile_man);
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView name;

        ImageView pic;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a generic `List`, which will contain `Object` instances. That means any instance of the `Object` class or a class that extends `Object` (essentially all of them). When you attempt to get an item out of that list, the compiler knows that it's an `Object`, but your method signature is saying you're returning an `Album`; the compiler doesn't know that the element you're retrieving from the list **definitely is** an `Album`, so it can't compile the code.

You can solve this is one of two ways. You can declare your `List` to only contain instances of the `Album` class:

```
List<Album> items = new ArrayList<Album>();
```

Or you can cast the object you're retrieving from the list, to tell the compiler that **you** are definite that it's an `Album` even if it isn't:

```
Album getItem(int position) {
    return (Album)items.get(position);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the informative answer. (And thanks to all the others as well)

Answer (score 1):

Try to make your list this way:

```
List<Album> items = new ArrayList<Album>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the specialized form of the List/ArrayList, or cast the result yourself.

```
Album getItem(int position) {
    return (Album)items.get(position);
}
```

or better:

```
private List<Album> items = new ArrayList<Album>();
```